# Config.DEBUG deprecated

Tags: android, android-debug

I am trying to add a following code.

```
    if (Config.DEBUG) {
    // do something
    } else {
    // do something
    }
```

I realized that Config.DEBUG is deprecated in API 14. What is the alternative if it?

Comment: Use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` instead of `Config.DEBUG`..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
    // do something
}else{
    // do something
}
```

It's not really documented anywhere but seems to work in both eclipse and Android Studio (latest versions respectively).

Returns `true` if the current build is a debug build and `false` if it's an release. Since it's not documented anywhere be wary of using it in production code since it may be stripped at any time (and there are reports of incorrectly attributing releases to debug builds).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same earlier but it was not referencing BuildConfig class but now it is referencing. Not sure, what exactly happened earlier. Thanks